# How does this syntax of 'let' work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've read a lot of documentation on the `let` keyword in JavaScript, and I understand that the spec is still being revised and updated, but I've come across a usage of `let` which I have yet to see, and I was curious how this syntax works.

For context, it appears in [nervgh/angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/src/services/FileDrop.js), and this is the syntax usage I cannot understand:

`let { forEach } = angular;`

I see later in the code that `forEach` is used like so:

`forEach(this.uploader._directives.over, this._removeOverClass, this);`

It almost appears to be used as a namespace assignment.

Comment: @pwee167 No, it is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: As @Vohuman said, this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword . The other duplicate is correct though.

Comment: I nominate this question for reopening to it can be closed with the correct duplicate. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300952/removing-wrong-duplicate-flag-when-there-is-a-correct-duplicate-flag

Comment: @Jan - I agree with your comment about the wrong duplicate. My misunderstanding was about the destructuring syntax, not the let keyword which just happened to be used in the example of destructuring I provided. The first duplicate didn't contain the information I sought in the first place, which led me to asking this question.